# Genericity of equivariant embeddings

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to ask an equivariant version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812907/genericity-of-embeddings-of-closed-manifolds).

Let $M$ be a closed manifold equipped with the action of a compact Lie group $G$. By the Mostow-Palais embedding theorem, $M$ can be embedded equivariantly into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, where $G$ is realized as a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

**Vague question:** Suppose $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous $G$-equivariant map. I'd like to know how close $f$ is to an embedding, if we are allowed to make $n$ arbitrarily large.

One attempt at a more precise phrasing:

**Question 1:** Let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous $G$-equivariant map. Is it true that (assuming $n$ is sufficiently large) for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a continuous $G$-equivariant embedding $f':M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the image of $f'$ is contained in the $\epsilon$-ball around the image of $f$?

More generally:

**Question 2:** What if $G$ is a non-compact linear group but the quotient $G\backslash M$ is compact?

Comment: In the title you wrote "genericity" but you're asking about "density"

Comment: It seems from the two answers below, the condition you want is not "$n$ sufficiently large" but "all relevant $G$-representations occur with sufficiently large multiplicity". That means if you fix $G$ compact but not finite and some dimension $k$ , then there might not be a $G$ action on some fixed $\mathbb R^n$ that works for all $G$-manifolds of dimension $\le k$.

Comment: I erased my answer as it was inaccurate. Still Q1 is unclear, as it is not said in how $\mathbb{R}^n$ comes with a $G$-action, which in particular makes "for large $n$" very unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Wasserman (*Equivariant Differential Topology*, Topology, **8**(1969), pp. 127-150) proved a generalized Whitney embedding theorem under the assumption that $G$ is compact.

Below you can find the statement of one of his theorems (Corollary 1.10 in the above-mentioned paper).

**Def**. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$. A $G$-manifold $M$ is *subordinate* to $V$ if $\forall x \in M \exists U$ invariant neighbourhood of $x$ and equivariant smooth embedding $U\to V^k $ for some $k>0$.

**Thm**(Wasserman) If $M^n$ is subordinate to $V$, then any equivariant smooth map $f:M\to V^k$ can be approximated $C^r$ and uniformly  by an equivariant immersion if $k\geq 2n$ and equivariant 1-1 immersion if $k\geq 2n+1$. If $C$ is a closed subset of $M$, and $f|C$ is an immersion (or embedding)the approximation may be chosen to agree with $f$ on $C$.